# Get value of hidden input to jquery

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I am working in wordpress and I have created a custom plugin.In which I have get multiple data from the database and my code is like this.

```
<?php 
foreach($result as $res)
{    
?>
<input type="hidden" class="status" value="<?php echo $res->review_status; ?>" />
<button class="aprove" value="<?php echo $res->review_id; ?>">Aprove</button>
<?php 
}
?>
```

Now, I want to get hidden field value in jQuery. My jQuery code is like this:

```
 jQuery(".aprove").click(function(){
     var status = jQuery('.status').val();
     alert(status);
     });
```

When I click on button then it shows only first value of hidden field. For instance, the fist hidden value is 1 and second value is 0 then it display only fist value 1 for both button. So what shold I have to do to get different hidden value?

Comment: you have to create a jquery array and puss all hidden value in them and then do what ever stuff you want to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your answer. for each button the value taken would be from the input element before the button element

```
 jQuery(".aprove").click(function(){
    var status = jQuery(this).prev('.status').val();
    alert(status);
 });
```

Comment: It works in fiddle but i dont know why i got an error in my localhost .

Comment: have u included the line.<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: It was my mistake. I had put hidden field in another <td> not in <td> of <button>. Therefor, it gave "undefine" error. Now it works. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 5):

Try :

```
jQuery(".aprove").click(function(){
    jQuery('.status').each(function(){
        var status = jQuery(this).val();
        alert(status);
    });
});
```

[.each](https://api.jquery.com/each/) will loop through all the classes and it will give alert every value of it.

[JS Fiddel Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/1z3hsemr/embedded/result/)

**Updated**

[Updated Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/1z3hsemr/1/embedded/result/)

Comment: I want only one value when i click on button.

Answer (score 1):

```
 var status = jQuery('.status').val();
 alert(status);
```

this will get the value of element first found on page and will return the result,

if you want all the input values use

> jquery **each()** -  https://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/

```
jQuery('.status').each(function(){
   alert($(this).val());
 });
```

// this will give you all the values you want, one by one

Answer (score 0):

you can use **.map** like this to get what you want:

```js
   $(document).ready(function(){
       var status=[]
       jQuery(".aprove").click(function(){
        status = $(".status").map(function() {
          return $(this).val();
       }).get();
       alert(status);//array of values
           });
      });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <input type="hidden" class="status" value="0" />
     <input type="hidden" class="status" value="1" />
   <button class="aprove" value="">Aprove</button>
```